# Git history graph compared to SVN history graph

Tags: git, svn, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am trying to understand the difference between a Git and SVN graph. I know that the Git graph is a DAG

But when comparing these two:

Example Git history graph:
http://gugod.org/2009/12/12/3389620_29acb2fe86d3e03e7f8c665c4225c454.jpg

Example SVN history graph:
http://svn-graph-branches.googlecode.com/svn/wiki/nxt-python-r222.svg

I don't really know how to apply that knowledge - the seem pretty similar to me.

Here:

http://ericsink.com/vcbe/html/directed_acyclic_graphs.html

It says that:
*Second generation tools tend to model the history of a repository as a line*

But that does not really fit with the above SVN example of the history graph - so either SVN is not a second generation tool or the article is wrong. Could someone help with clarifying the above?

Comment: SVN isn't 2nd generation :)

Comment: I think it's pretty safe to say that the SVN graph will also be a DAG. In most cases it will generally be a simpler DAG, because SVN workflows don't generally entail as much branching/merging/etc...

Comment: Ok but if both SVN and Git is implemented as a DAG then I guess the only difference is how merge, branching etc. is implemented?

Comment: Actually SVN is the prime example of a "second generation" tool: http://ericsink.com/vcbe/html/history_of_version_control.html

Comment: If you want to defer to some random web page that considers anything not DVCS to be 2nd generation then sure.  That's a pretty bizarro definition to me.

Comment: How else should it be broken down? So far I've seen ERic Sink's "First Generation", "Second Generation", DVCS/"Third Generation" breakdown, I've seen a Local/Centralized/Distributed breakdown, and then this: http://codicesoftware.blogspot.com/2010/11/version-control-timeline.html It seems a pretty reasonable high-level classification to me.

Comment: Personally I would say that whether or not something is atomic per-file or per-repository is a pretty enormous difference, which they don't specifically address.  It also appears that the article they site from Eric Raymond was written based on SVN 1.4, which was prior to the introduction of merge tracking. Lumping CVS, early Clearcase, Newer Clearcase, old SVN, and new SVN into a single generation is just confusing.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is, that in SVN, everybody always has the same sequence of commits. In SVN, a fully up-to-date working copy is a defined thing, and it always has exactly the same ordering of nodes.

In Git, a repository can be fully "up to date" with respect to another repository, but a third repository might have a completely different set of nodes after a certain point of shared history.

In other words, if I create version 5 in SVN, and the commit immediately before it in chronological order is version 4, then eventually everybody on the project is going to have to see that same version 5. I know that version 3 came before version 4 and that nobody could possibly have a version 5' that I will need to merge. The order will always be, in every working copy everywhere, 3-4-5-5'.

But in distributed tools like Git or Mercurial, if I create version 397afeg815, and the version immediately before it chronologically is 8290e7ab8f, that tells me nothing at all about where version 839eabcdef7 might fall, and some guy over in China might have just committed version 9876543231abc that also comes exactly after 8290e7ab8f. The tree branches here, it is not linear; there is no defined order beyond parent-child relationships. Unlike SVN where every commit has exactly one parent, and at most one child (on the same branch), in Git or Mercurial a commit can have multiple parents and multiple children in the same branch.

When SVN branches, it is a deliberate choice, and everybody will see the branch at the same point, and there is no question about which line of development is the trunk going forward. Git and Mercurial and other similar systems potentially create a new branch with every single commit, and whether any given commit is on "trunk" depends entirely on a team's development process or even just on who you're asking.

**Edit for further clarification**

The difference between a true DAG like Git or Mercurial, and a "linear" history like SVN is, you can rearrange the nodes in Git's DAG as you see fit. You'll still have the same history. In fact, depending on what order you pull/commit/push things in, you may actually see several different permutations of the DAG in your own repositories. The order of nodes does not matter, only the parent-child relationship.

SVN's history is different. There is only ONE way to view an SVN tree. Version 2 always follows version 1. Version 3 always follows version 2. There is no question which order things happened in for a "linear" history. The order of the nodes is unchangeable. In SVN's case it even crosses branch boundaries.

Comment: hm I think I understand your point but had hoped for a more abstract/less detailed explanation - using a specific sequence of  commits as explanation is not that clear. I think its strange that when you get to the Git/DAG part and SVN differences it difficult to find a concise definition/drawing that is simple and possible to understand.

Comment: OK. Look again at the two pictures you linked. The SVN picture shows a bunch of branches, all starting from various places, but then they all pretty much stay separate. Each branch has exactly one line of development. Branches may be born and die but they progress pretty linearly, and every user will see the same graph. The Git picture also shows a bunch of branches, all starting from various places, but these branches merge together, branch off each other, merge with each other, and make a tangled mess. Also, this is only ONE view of the graph. Every person may see something different.